# match string after period regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to make a regex to match the text after `settings.` in the following string

`GPIO.setup(settings.pic_taken_led , GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)`  IE (`pic_taken_led`)

I have so far come up with `/(?<=settings)([.]\w+)/g` but it matches *with* the period and I need it *without* the period. (`.pic_taken_led`).

I feel I am close but I can't remove the period from the capture expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=settings\.)\w+
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hws482/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=settings\.)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `settings.` string
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits, `_`s.

VSCode demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are really close. Since you want to capture `pic_taken_led`, just capture the String after `.`
So your regex should be `(?<=settings).(\w+)`

Comment: Why bother with `[.]` instead of just `.`?

Comment: sorry, `\.` not `.`. Although `.` probably will work also

Comment: I tried to put that in regexer and vscode and it's still picking up the period. https://regexr.com/5ea70

Comment: @NoleloN This regex does match with the period but capture group 1 is `pic_taken_led`.  You mentioned  matching and "the capture expression" so it is a little confusing.  Depends on how you are going to use this ultimately.  I upvoted both answers.